# Unable to parse jsp indexOf statement correctly

Tags: java

It appears that the `.indexOf("://")` portion of this .jsp file is breaking the proper rendering of this file... how can I escape this to ensure it's not a problem?

```
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${cssFile.indexOf("://") > 0}"><link rel="stylesheet" href="${cssFile}" type="text/css" /></c:when>
            <c:otherwise><link rel="stylesheet" href="/cmt/css/${cssFile}" type="text/css" /></c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>  
...
     test='${fn:indexOf(cssFile, "://") > 0}'
```